# Opposite prefix for 'ethno-'

Tags: prefixes

Is there one? A cursory Google search yielded none. My best guess would be something close to *exic-*; not that I can think of any relevant words in this context using that.

Comment: Before anyone can even begin to think what the word for the opposite would be, one would have to have some idea of what the opposite itself is. Could you explain what it is that you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

The opposite prefix of *ethno-* is *xeno-*.

**Xeno-:** Relating to a foreigner or foreigners.

**Origin:**
From Greek *xenos* ‘stranger, foreigner’, (adjective) ‘strange’. 
[(Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/xeno-)

Compare this to:

**Ethno-:**
Ethnic; ethnological.

**Origin:**
From Greek ethnos ‘nation’. [(Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ethno-)

> *Xenocentrism is the opposite of ethnocentrism,* and refers to the belief that another culture is superior to one’s own. (The Greek root word xeno, pronounced “ZEE-no,” means “stranger” or “foreign guest.”) An exchange student who goes home after a semester abroad or a sociologist who returns from the field may find it difficult to associate with the values of their own culture after having experienced what they deem a more upright or nobler way of living. [(Link)](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/alamo-sociology/chapter/ethnocentrism-and-xenocentricism/)

Comment: *Ethnocentrism* could arguably be the opposite of *xenocentrism*, but *ethno-* is not generally the opposite of *xeno-*. The prefix *ethno-* conveys the idea of having to do with **a** people (nation, culture), but it is silent on whether the people in question is one's own or some other one. In *ethnocentrism* that is implied, but the implication is not carried by the prefix *ethno-*. In fact, the meanings of some words containing that prefix (*ethnology, ethnography*) have to do primarily with cultures other than one's own.