# Name of phobia for fear/dislike of locals?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, phobias

Here in South Africa there are about 30 million documented foreigners, from mainly Zimbabwe. Some restaurants have only foreigners as managers and only foreigners as staff, with no room for locals to find work.
The word *xenophobia* refers to the hatred or fear of foreigners by locals.

What is the word referring to the hatred or fear of *locals* by locals themselves?

Comment: Are these restaurants also owned by people living in a different country than yours? Are these restaurants serving mainly foreign food or mainly domestic food?  It's hardly unusual, for example, for "Chinese restaurants" (meaning restaurants that serve Chinese food) to employ people from China anywhere in the world. Do migrant workers holding foreign passports routinely accept lower pay than those with domestic passports? Are you looking for a word that describes complex ethnic hatreds rather than simple economic factors because you've misunderstood what's causing these employment patterns?

Comment: I would argue, by definition, it's not possible for the self to deprecate / lift itself.  But, what happens is that the self and the other become blurred so that other things come into the picture of the self.  And, that a self that hates itself, likely hates everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The ["opposite" prefix](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/529914/2637) to ***xeno-*** is ***ethno-***, which led me to [this Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ethnophobia) for a term with apparently two diametrically opposed senses...

> **ethnophobia**  (countable and uncountable, plural **ethnophobias**)
> The irrational fear and hatred of one's own nation.
> The hatred of any race or ethnicity different to one's own.

In case you're wondering, it's not in the full Oxford English Dictionary. But I'd expect it to be understood *in context* by competent Anglophones on first encounter. The OED doesn't have [***ethnophile***](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-lm&q=define%20ethnophile) either, but it's easy to find dozens of online definitions for that if you don't understand it straight off.

Comment: Whatever the Wiktionary may say, any attempt to use the word for the 'fear and hatred of one's own nation' would be likely to cause confusion.

Comment: Indeed. I just found [*{the inhabitants} remained an **ethnically insular** and, some might argue, protective, even **ethnophobic**, or at the least **ethnocentric**, group in a predominately Buddhist or animist world*.](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Creative_in_Struggle/bOk-ivwxZ1oC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=ethnophobic&pg=PA90&printsec=frontcover) Where the first ***ethno-*** seems to refer ***other*** ethnic groups, whereas the second makes more sense if I assume it refers to the inhabitants' ***own*** ethnic group.

Answer (score 1):

A search for antonyms of *xenophobia* gives, among others, the word **oikophobia**.

[Wiktionary *oikophobia*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oikophobia)
2. Dislike of one's own culture or compatriots.

[Wikipedia *oikophobia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oikophobia)
"The term has been used in political contexts to refer critically to political ideologies that are held to repudiate one's own culture and laud others."

(The root *oiko-* has the same source as the root *eco-* in the word *ecology*.)

An antonym of *xenophopbia* can also be formed by making the other of its two roots an opposite, as *xenophilia*, which could mean preferring foreigners to the disadvantage of locals.
[Wiktionary *xenophilia*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/xenophilia)
1.an attraction to or love of foreign people, manners or culture

Comment: Reminds me of *carpetbaggers*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use the expression:

***[Intraethnic](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/intraethnic#:%7E:text=Adjective,Within%20an%20ethnic%20group)*** hatred.

(Wiktionary)

Answer (score 0):

> What is the word referring to the hatred or fear of locals by locals themselves?

The question itself is badly phrased and uses the word "local" equivocally - in one meaning it is *"those living in the area who are **not** born and bred in the area"*, and in the other *"those living in the area who **are** born and bred in the area".*

In the eyes of those who resent Zimbabweans (mainly Shona), Zimbabweans are not "locals".

Of a "local" is a person who was born and brought up in the locality/area, then the Zimbabweans clearly are not "locals".

You are thus asking about the dislike of foreigners - **xenophobia**.

Comment: In the quoted sentence, surely the word *locals* has the same meaning in both instances, "not-foreigners" or perhaps "home-grown". Why are home-grown business owners only employing foreign staff and no-one home-grown?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Home-grown managers are not mentioned. The problem is a cartel of Zimbabweans who own and run restaurants staffed by only Zimbabweans.